# MySQL flatten Json array to string of values

Tags: mysql, json, sphinx

I have a JSON field in mysql for tags like so

```
[
    {"id": 138001, "tag": "Travel"}, 
    {"id": 138002, "tag": "Holidays"}
]
```

and I want to retrieve it as 'Travel Holidays'

I can get the values in the a json array format:

```
["Travel", "Holidays"]
```

with the current statement,

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(post_tags, '$[*].tag') AS tags FROM posts WHERE post_id = 646745;
```

but I'm not sure if there is a way to flatten the array into a single string separated by spaces, is it possible?

My reason for doing this, is that sphinx search indexes the tags field also and you can get the id values in the index which isn't desired at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could just let sphinx index `["Travel", "Holidays"]` directly.

As per `charset_table` rules, the `[`, `"` and `,` will just be 'ignored' (more technically treated as separators and collapsed away)

---

Also not familiar with it, but maybe `JSON_UNQUOTE` could work? Don't know if it can collapse arrays.

Comment: Being a noob with sphinx, I was unaware of the charset_table, that is exactly what i needed to learn, thank you.

Comment: `charset_table` is kinda the workhorse of sphinx indexing, understanding how it works (even if ultimately dont need to change it) is kinda the 'coming of age' in using sphinx. No longer can be considered noob, now intermediate :)

Comment: Lol thanks mate, I have been on a binge learning experience in sphinx config and are earning that intermediate status ;)